# java sorting grades by grades, names

Tags: java, sorting, names

The outcome of this code is to move the mergedGrades into a sortedGrades based on sorting it by grades, and then names. I manage to find the highest to lowest grades, but I am not able to sort the grades by names. Please help.

My code:

```
        public static Grades sort(Grades mergedGrades, Grades repeat) {
          Grades sortedGrades = new Grades();
            while( (mergedGrades.size() > 0)){
            Grade highComp = null;
            Grade highest = mergedGrades.get(0);

            int index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < mergedGrades.size(); j++) {
                highComp = mergedGrades.get(j);
                if (highComp.getGpa() > highest.getGpa()) {
                    highest = highComp;
                }
            }
            //sortedGrades.add(highest);

            for(int i = 0 ; i < mergedGrades.size(); i++){
                       for (int i = 0; i < repeat.size(); i++) {
                if (repeat.contains(highest)) {
           if(highest.getFirstName().compareTo(repeat.get(i).getFirstName()) < 0) {
        if(mergedGrades.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(highest.getLastName()) < 0) {
                            sortedGrades.add(highest);
                            System.out.println("test");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sortedGrades.add(highest);
            mergedGrades.remove(index);

        }
```

the outcome should looks like this:

> ```
>    S005: Stacy, Lu 4.0
>    S004: Aseef, Hernandez 3.9
>    S006: Aseef, Nilkund 3.9
>    S002: Jim, NLN 3.9
>    S003: Misty, Fang 3.9
>    S009: Steve, Calderon 3.9
>    S016: Aseef, Simmons 3.9
>    S010: Raj, Singh 3.8
>    S018: Hamza, Nilkund 3.5
>    S012: Kathy, Calderon 3.5
>    S017: Hifza, Nilkund 3.3
>    S011: Jason, Kramer 3.3
>    S001: John, Rodgers 3.3
>    S019: Chris, Peach 3.2
>    S013: Roopa, Singh 3.2
>    S020: Ramona, Luke 2.4
>    S014: Amid, Naveed 2.4
>    S015: Faith, Williams 1.0
> ```

Comment: Please post [mcve] including the definition of  `Grades` and  test data

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `hashCode()` values is not the way to sort names.  Use `compareTo()` instead:

```
if (mergedGrades.get(i).getFirstName().compareTo(
            highest.getFirstName()) < 0) {
   // mergedGrades firstname < highest firstname
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I tried to edit it with it but still not working right.

Comment: This is only a solution to a very small part of the problem.  You need to take a step back and reevaluate your sorting algorithm as a whole.